# Internal links still point to development subdomain?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, migration, subdomain, shared-hosting

I moved a wordpress site from a subdirectory `http://www.development.example.com` to the root `public_html` directory.
I have updated the site & home urls to `http://www.example.com` and verified in phpMyAdmin in the control panel. The header links to other pages work as expected but my internal jump links on the home page such as `http://www.example.com/#about` still point to the subdomain link `http://www.development.example.com/#about`. Is there another place in the admin dashboard or directly in the database that I can check for necessary url changes to resolve this?

Comment: I also tried inserting `update_option( 'siteurl', 'http://www.example.com' );
update_option( 'home', 'http://www.example.com' );` into the theme's `function.php` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try a couple things.

1.) Add the following to your wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://yourdomain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://yourdomain.com');
```

2.) If you have (SSH) access to [WP CLI](http://wp-cli.org/), you can run this in your site root:

```
wp search-replace oldomain.com newdomain.com
```

3.) Try the [Better Search Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/) plugin.

Comment: I had already added #1 to `wp-config.php`. I initially used the "Search & Replace Plugin" which did not work but the "_Better_ Search Replace" plugin you suggested caught extra results and did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Please update query in your database

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
```

Change you **oldomain** link and **newdomain** link

I hope this help of you

Comment: I prefer this query approach instead of plugins & manually inserting statements into files. I'll try this next time I migrate a wp site.